# RAM and CPU compared to mobo clock

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard

I have a general question concerning RAM and CPU speeds compared to a motherboard speed.
Motherboards have e.g. 100-133MHz clock. CPUs have some frequency multipliers 
and memories I suppose have some as well. 
And here's my question. What CPUs and RAMs are doing while waiting for motherboard to tick?
Is a motherboard frequency the frequency RAM and CPU are communication with each other?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The System bus connects the CPU to the RAM, and operates at the same speeds the RAM does. This is why your CPU, Motherboard, and RAM all match in capacity (speed). Do not confuse this with clock speed however.

You CPU and Motherboard should both indicate the speeds of ram they will support. buy ram at one of these supported speeds (even better, consult your motherboard RAM compatibility list), and you will have no troubles.

See here for a list of common DDR3 speeds:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM#JEDEC_standard_modules

Also, since you seem interested in clock ticks, remember, the first D in DDR is Double, because DDR performs operations on both the rising and falling edge of the modified tick.

Comment: If I understand it right, the frequency CPU is talking with RAMs is different from the mobo clock frequency (e.g. 1 333MHz)?

Comment: System bus speed (formerly known as Front side Bus speed) is different from CPU clock speed, yes, but remember the CPU coordinates the memory access, so actions are initiated on the CPU clock (modified) tick. The FSB speed is just the speed of the bus interconnecting them. This is why the CPU, mobo, and RAM must all agree on a speed to operate at.

Comment: Thanks, now it seems clearer. 
And how is FSB speed related to the mobo clock speed?

Comment: perhaps thats the confusion. the motherboard doesn't have a clock speed. the mobo is made to work with a chip that does have a clock speed, so its buses and integrated components will operate at compatible speeds, but the different buses don't have clocks of their own. the CPU provides all the clocking across the system, so that everyone marches at the beat of the same drum. Don't assume that everything that is measured in cycles is driven by its own clock. most CPUs can't access data in ram on every modified tick, but a faster bus to ram allows it to do so with fewer interstitial ticks.

Comment: Oh I see. So the FSB speed (and other buses speeds) are fractions of the CPU clock speed.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

They measure different things, like in a car you have RPM for an engine and your tires have a different RPM because there are gears in between. CPU cycles are used to perform math, ram cycles are used to input and retrieve data and motherboard cycles move data around.

This is an oversimplified example, there are other things happening as well.